# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType'

Tags: python

The code runs fine in Jupyter Notebook but when I run it in Colab, I get the error:

float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType'

The code where this occurs is:

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
# Fit and transform the train data
X_train[cols_for_impute] = imputer.fit_transform(X_train[cols_for_impute])

# Transform the test data
X_test[cols_for_impute] = imputer.transform(X_test[cols_for_impute])
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should check what you have in variables - maybe you really has some `None`, `NaN` in data. Maybe it uses different data then you expect and maybe it needs code to remove/replace `None`, `NaN`, etc..

Comment: Hi and thanks. To put the full error code is quite long, but I can do that if it helps. There are NaN values in the dataset and I want to use the KNN Imputer to treat them.  What is odd is that when I run the same code in my Jupyter Notebook its works fine but when I tried it on Google Colab, I got this error message.

Comment: Google Colab may use different version which may have changes and it may work in different way.

Comment: put error message. You could also add minimal working code with example data which makes problem so we could test it on our computers. Code and data you could put on GitHub and add link in question (not comment) so more people will see it.

Comment: Traceback 
<ipython-input-91-f06c3ff61368> in <module>()
      1 # Fit and transform the train data
----> 2 X_train[cols_for_impute] = imputer.fit_transform(X_train[cols_for_impute])
      3 
      4 # Transform the test data
      5 X_test[cols_for_impute] = imputer.transform(X_test[cols_for_impute])
5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType'

Comment: read my first comment again: put error **in question, not in comment**. It will be more readable and more people will see it.